# Can I use GitHub and be PCI DSS compliant?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope, git

Is it possible to use any remote DVCS (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) with PCI DSS or should I host Git on my own server?

Comment: it depends on your scope - I think you need to add some details ...

Comment: Use GitHub for what? public or private repository?

Comment: @schroeder Payment system aggregator

Comment: @crovers Of course private :)

Comment: This question & its answers are outdated - they were true in the 3.x era of the PCI DSS standard, but the requirements changed with 4.0, the question relevant to 4.0 version of the standard (and hopefully 4.x) is here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270951/can-i-use-github-and-be-pci-dss-4-0-compliant

Comment: @bbozo the question is not outdated, just the answer.

Comment: Questions about a standard should include the version of the standard. This question is low quality because there is no context. The question poses two scenarios (GitHub or self-host). Both present problems for PCI compliance. Both can be compliant. Compliance requires details and those details must be documented.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note : not a QSA, but I do have some PCI experience.

There is nothing in PCI about storage of source code **[mod note: this was true pre-version 4.0]**. There are requirements about change management, which github would help with, but nothing about where source code should be or any requirements to keep source code private (it allows use of open source, after all).  Given a private repo and assuming you do not store authentication information (keys, appids, passwords, api keys, certificates), PCI governed data or PII in GitHub repositories (which you shouldn't be doing anyways), you are probably fine using GitHub.  Talk to your QSA if you want to be sure.

Comment: This is all correct - I'm a QSA. Just need to sure there's separation of duties between dev/test and production environments and people responsible for each. i.e. don't allow an admin access to and ability to change source code and later deploy to production environments.